# JSON response data not producing output

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON data similar to  below :

```
[
    {
        "EmployeePersonal":
        {
            "id":"1",
            "epf_no":"111\/22",
            "name":"Abcd Efgh",
            "status":"1",
            "entry_by":"1"
        },
        "District":
        {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Sivasagar"
        }
    }
]
```

And in the `HTML` , I tried to alert the employee name within $.ajax() :

```
    success:function(resp) {
            alert(resp.EmployeePersonal.name);
            $('#employee_name').html(resp.EmployeePersonal.name);
   }
```

But the above code alerts nothing !

NB: if I `alert(resp)`, it alerts `[object Object]`.

Comment: you need to use `alert(JSON.stringify(resp))`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
alert(resp[0].EmployeePersonal.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your variable `resp` may not be passed in a JSON format accepted by your browser.
Changing it to:
`resp = JSON.stringify(resp)`
will ensure that it's the right format.

Next, the actual object isn't just a JSON, it's a JSON Array with just one element.
So, if you access the elements using `resp[0].EmployeePersonal.name`, it should return the proper value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider if you have a JSON like below:

```
var json = [
    {
        "EmployeePersonal":
        {
            "id":"1",
            "epf_no":"111\/22",
            "name":"Abcd Efgh",
            "status":"1",
            "entry_by":"1"
        },
        "District":
        {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Sivasagar"
        }
    }
]
```

then you can access it by using,

```
alert(json[0].EmployeePersonal.name);
```

You are getting an array of JSON data. You need to specify the index in order to access the name of the EmployeePersonal.